# Consuming IAsyncEnumerable via HttpClient (HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead) to Blazor WASM not cancelling

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, cancellation, minimal-apis

I would like to consume an IAsyncEnumerable via a HttpClient from a Blazor-Page.
The stream of the results works properly but in case of cancelling the request, the Task does not end on the server side.

Server-Side Code (Sample Code->results in an endless-loop):

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Post([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILogger<Program> logger)
{
    logger?.LogInformation($"Called Server");
    var i = 0;
    while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        logger?.LogInformation($"Send item {i}");
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        yield return new WeatherForecast
        (
               DateTime.Now.AddDays(i),
               Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
              WeatherForecastController.Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(WeatherForecastController.Summaries.Length)]
         );
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Client-Side (Cancellation via Button):

```
this._cts = new();
 using var client = factory.CreateClient("Default");
    using var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
    req.SetBrowserResponseStreamingEnabled(true);
var response = await client.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, this._cts.Token);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(this._cts.Token);
    var weatherForcasts = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<WeatherForecast>(
         responseStream,
         new JsonSerializerOptions
             {
                 PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                 DefaultBufferSize = 128
             }
     , this._cts.Token);


    await foreach (var weatherForecast in weatherForcasts)
    {
        if (this._cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
        forecasts.Add(weatherForecast);
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
When i try to iterate through a loop without "yield return" inside only awaiting a Delay, the cancellation works properly. After canelling the client request, the cancelationtoken of the server-call will be canceled as well.

Comment: You can't cancel a server side task remotely from the client.

Comment: It seems that you should consider switching to SignalR instead of using ordinary HTTP requests.

Comment: @GuruStron just want to display results while loading. Or have the possibility to cancel the call. In production there will be a long time sql-query operation with sub queries to gather metadata. I dont want to have a persitent connection like signalR

Comment: @liam are you sure? then why does asp.net pass a cancellation token to the controller action?

Comment: The controller action is not client side @Darragh

Comment: @Liam if the request is long running, as it is in this case, then you can cancel it . https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: That is also server side, not client side. The browser does not know what a cancellation token is...

Answer (score -1):

## 3 Things

### 1# Bad usage of infinite loop server side

You do have an infinite loop, server side an `HttpRequest` really isn't intended to be essentially a continuous connection. Like one comment your treating this as a persistent connection, so `SignalR` may very well be a better choice. As is the only way to stop this code ***IS*** through cancelation, and frankly looks like an abusive technique forcing a scenario onto `HttpClient`.

`HttpRequests` should at the end of the day should have a normal path of start and end clearly defined, Request/Response behavior, even with `IAsyncEnumerable` the idea is the client can start the Request and the server can start Responding with the first available items while not making you wait for them all.

### #2 Faster Cancelation

If you want your cancelation to be more immediate, this may have to do with how your canceling the loop.

`await foreach (var weatherForecast in weatherForcasts)`

the `IAsyncEnumerable` itself has a cancelation process

`await foreach (var weatherForecast in weatherForcasts.WithCancellation(this._cts.Token))`

Without this `WithCancellation` added you are technically forced to wait till the next item is fully received before you are able exit the loop.

### #3 CancelationToken behavior

While not deeply documented, most MSFT methods only honor listening to a `CancelationToken` at the most immediate entry to a method. You could decompile or pop over to GitHub to the relevant code to see what its doing but its usually faster to assume like I've stated already. So like in #2 you have to use AND handle cancelation in every place necessary